# How to extract multiples of a number from a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector let's say

`x <- 1:1000`

and I want to extract the multiples of 8 from it.

What should I do?
(I don't want to do `x[-c(8,16,24,.....)]` )

The goal is to remove the multiples of 8 from the `x` vector.

Comment: modulo operator is the normal way `res <- x[!x%%8]`

Comment: Do you mean the indices that are a multiple of 8 or just the values that are a multiple of 8?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I mean the values that are a multiple of 8.

Comment: `res <- x[x%%8]`, not `res <- x[!x%%8]` could be the solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For this you can use the modulo operator, i.e. `%%`. Take for example:

```
> 322%%8
[1] 2
```

which tells you that after dividing 322 by 8, 2 remains, i.e. 320 is exactly 40 times 8, leaving 2.

In you example we can use `%%` combined with subsetting to get the the multiples of 8. Remember that `%%` yields 0 for exact multiples of 8:

```
input = 1:1000
multiple_of_8 = (input %% 8) == 0
head(multiple_of_8)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
length(multiple_of_8)
[1] 1000
```

also note that `%%` is a vectorized operation, i.e. of the left hand side is a vector, the result will also be a vector. The `multiple_of_8` vector now contains 1000 logicals stating if that particular element of `input` is an exact multiple of 8. Using that logical vector to subset get's you the result you need:

```
input[multiple_of_8]
  [1]    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80   88   96  104  112  120
 [16]  128  136  144  152  160  168  176  184  192  200  208  216  224  232  240
 [31]  248  256  264  272  280  288  296  304  312  320  328  336  344  352  360
 [46]  368  376  384  392  400  408  416  424  432  440  448  456  464  472  480
 [61]  488  496  504  512  520  528  536  544  552  560  568  576  584  592  600
 [76]  608  616  624  632  640  648  656  664  672  680  688  696  704  712  720
 [91]  728  736  744  752  760  768  776  784  792  800  808  816  824  832  840
[106]  848  856  864  872  880  888  896  904  912  920  928  936  944  952  960
[121]  968  976  984  992 1000
```

or more compactly:

```
input[(input %% 8) == 0]
```

Comment: @germcd could you provide a bit more context to what you are doing. This could be done in a new answer.

Comment: I used integer division. it's the same as `8*1:125`